# How to call a hashmap & its values from other class in java?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I would like to create 5-6 classes,I am storing values in hashmap in 1st class & I would like to call it from 4th,5th & 6th class.How to get this  any snippets or example to implement this will be helpful,Thanks

Comment: What is "5-6"? Is this homework?

Comment: I think your question is not clear. More explanation is helpful.

Comment: could you clarify your problem a little better? did you try anything by yourself?

Comment: Sorry for making the stuff complex,how to access hashmap of other class.

Comment: Maybe you should start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public class Example {

    private HashMap<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public HashMap<String, String> getHashmap() {
        return hashmap;
    }

    public void setHashmap(HashMap<String, String> hashmap) {
        this.hashmap = hashmap;
    }
}

public class AnotherClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Example ex = new Example();
        HashMap<String, String> hm = ex.getHashmap();
    } 

}
```

Comment: I tried this way,it didn't work.Am I missin somethin here.I am getting all the hashmap values in the Main Class,but when Itry to call in the Another class its empty..

Answer (score 0):

you should use setters and getters for the hashmap.

```
private HashMap h = null;
//instantiate hashmap in the constructor
public ...
//add value to hashmap
public void add(Object value)
{
    h.put(value);//eventually cast value or declare it as you did it in the hashmap 
}

//get hashmap
public HashMap getMap()
{ 
    return h;
}

//set hashmap
public void setMap(HashMap hm)
{ 
    h=hm;
}...
```

Answer (score 0):

Two reasonable approaches.

1. Have a public getter for the Map.  Class5 would the call   class1.getMap().doSomething().  Not much work (good) and outside classes can do anything they want to the map, e.g. clear(), which may or may not be good.
2. Write individual methods for the map, e.g. putIntoMap(), removeFromMap(), etc.  More work but you can restrict what outsiders can do.  If you don't want them able to clear(), don't write a ckearMap() method.

Purists have a "Law of Demeter" that says always do option 2 but IMHO that is often overkill.